# How do I get the libc development libraries for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install glibc-devel package in Ubuntu 12.04. I am VM Ware work station in my project and this package is one of the dependency to build project image. I tried to find information on google about this package but didnt find any staisfactory answer.

Is this package not supported in Ubuntu 12.04? If not then what is the alternative package for it.

Any help on this will be useful.

Comment: After `apt-get update` you can use `apt-cache search libc6 dev` to find eligible packages.

Answer (score 20):

The [build-essential [image: Install build-essential]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essential) package should sort you out.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 5):

If you *just* need the libc [header files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_files), install [libc6-dev [image: Install libc6-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libc6-dev).

If you prefer to install on the command-line, you can use:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

This is worth mentioning, as if you're using a compiler *other* than the version of GCC as provided by [build-essential [image: Install build-essential]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essential) / [gcc-defaults [image: Install gcc-defaults]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gcc-defaults), you may want to just install the `libc6-dev` package.

(Installing `build-essential` will work because it will cause `libc6-dev` to be installed. `libc6-dev` is what actually provides the header files that enable you to link against GNU libc.)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue, and I clone the `glibc` (GNU libc) source with the command:

```
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
```

It runs fine for me.

Comment: This does not appear to be the specific version present in Ubuntu. Also, the *source* is not what the OP needs, but simply the *headers*.