# How to install glibc-devel in ubuntu-12.04?

Tags: 12.04, glibc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the libc development libraries for Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158996/how-do-i-get-the-libc-development-libraries-for-ubuntu-12-04)

When I run the following command:

`sudo apt-get install glibc-devel`

I get the following error:

`E: Unable to locate package glibc-devel`

How do I resolve this issue ?

Comment: I know its a duplicate , however , the answer given there didn't solve my issue . Is there any alternative solution ?

Comment: Please describe a little more detail what you did, what happened and what you expected.

Answer (score 5):

Possible duplicate of [How do I get the libc  development libraries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158996/how-do-i-get-the-libc-development-libraries-for-ubuntu-12-04)?

Run the command from the terminal `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

The build package should also install the libc6-devel package for you as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. You canvot to close this question and mark it is duplicate, if you like.

Comment: I know its a duplicate , however the above command sudo apt-get install build-essential doesn't seems to solve my problem .

Comment: Then you will have to provide more detailed information as to which package and/or files you are looking to install.

Answer (score -3):

seems that the package is not in the LTS repository packages.

Comment: I need to run an old parallel framework cilk from MIT , the original version not that from Intel . They required me to have , but its ok , I just ran Ubuntu10.04 from Virtual Box , which surprisingly supports Cilk from MIT . I don't know much about the inner details of Ubuntu , I was doing an assignment on parallel programming and I needed to run the old cilk . So , had I had glibc in 12.04 , it had been beneficial .